# Python scripting - How to execute linux commands?

Tags: 12.04, python, scripts

I have to do a bunch of file copying, moving, svn check out commands, directory checking etc. and I'm trying to make a script to do it for me. I have basic python syntax, but I'm not sure how to use python to execute linux commands.
I know the linux commands needed for example sudo apt-get install subversion i just don't know how to wrap python around it.

Specifically, could anyone give examples on how to:

- Check if a package (like svn) is installed, if not then install it. I know this is a simple if-statement but no idea how to write it...
- Check if a folder with a specific name is installed, if not create it on the desktop/some other directory. Similar to the above I would assume.
- Move to a certain directory and execute a command (like I want to extract a .tgz file in a certain directory)

There's more but I want to grasp basic principles and actually learn how to execute linux commands using python scripting. Thanks for your time~

EDIT: I am specifically required to use python

Comment: Is there a specific reason for doing this in Python?  I'm asking as it sounds like bash is more suited to those three specific tasks.

Comment: Seconded, bash seems better. You could look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python if you're bent on using python.

Comment: My manager wants me to learn python instead of using bash, I'm a newbie intern.

Comment: [Google Python classes](https://www.google.se/?gfe_rd=cr&safe=off#q=google+python+class&safe=off) - seems as a good start.

Answer (score 5):

You surely can do everything using Python's built-in stuff from [os](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) and [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) modules.

A slightly tricky thing would be if you want your script to "interact" with the programs you're invoking (like "wait until it prints 'Press Enter to continue', then send it an Enter keypress) - for that you can use [pexpect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect/) module.

For slightly higher-level way have a look at the [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) library - besides running local commands it would also allow you to easily execute code on remote machines via SSH.

A small sample of code using Fabric:

```
if "dirty" in api.local("git describe --dirty", capture=True):
    print colors.red("""Your repository is dirty, commit any changes first""")
    sys.exit(1)
```

Reads almost like poetry:) Similar code in Bash would look like unintelligible mess in comparison...